# Angular Firebase Database Querying

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

This is my .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidate-reg-success',
  templateUrl: './candidate-reg-success.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidate-reg-success.component.css']
})
export class CandidateRegSuccessComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 
    debugger;
    const rootRef=firebase.database.ref();
    const mail=rootRef.child('candidates_list').orderByChild('email').equalTo('pranavkeke@gmail.com');
    console.log(mail);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I am trying to query the user from `candidates_list` table which has the email address pranavkeke@gmail.com.

But I am unable to console it. It shows a error like

> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'typeof database'.

Any solution to query angular firebase database?

Comment: `firebase.database.ref();` => `firebase.database().ref();`

Comment: sir when i changed like above they are showing firebase is not defined eroor?Please help me

Comment: That error message would have existed before the change too. It looks like you should use AngularFire's built-in querying capabilities: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md

Answer (score 3):

you need to inject the AngularFirebaseData  in constructor and change the code and try again

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable,   
   FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidate-reg-success',
 templateUrl: './candidate-reg-success.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./candidate-reg-success.component.css']
})
  export class CandidateRegSuccessComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) { 
    debugger;
    db.list('/candidates_list', ref => ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo('pranavkeke@gmail.com'));
}   
 ngOnInit() {
    }}
```

Comment: Hi @Chellappan வ this works perfectly for me can you give one example how can I query having multiple parameters like email name etc etc?

Comment: Can you check this:https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Comment: Yes I tried with fire store but was upset by getting this error I already have a question for this error on stack overflow but this question is not answered yet the error is This likely means that the library (@angular/fire/firestore) which declares AngularFirestore has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if 
the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Comment: It seems it's supported by angular 9+ https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/6.0.2

Comment: Yes thats the main problem do you know about the querybase? I was trying a hand over it I just ran the npm command and installed it but I dont know how to import and use this it would be great if you can provide some guidence here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113829/how-to-import-querybase-in-angular

Comment: In documentation also they have provided example have you check this:https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#example-app

Comment: Yes but thats about firestore which is not working currently as I showed you error so another option that I had is the Querybase thats developed by David East so was trying out that .Its just like an addon on firebase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218702/discussion-between-chellappan--and-kushal-baldev).